# Find the value of $\tan(x+100) = \tan(x+50)\tan(x)\tan(x-50)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the value of the expression $\tan(x+100) =\tan(x+50)\tan(x)\tan(x-50)$

This question has been bothering me for a while. Had it been $60$ instead of $50$, I could have written it as $\tan3x$. I'm not able to proceed at all. Would someone please help me to solve this question in a short and elegant method?

Comment: Are the angles in degrees?

Comment: Yes they are in degrees

Comment: Is your question really "find the value of $x$"?  If $x$ is unknown, then $\tan (x + 100^\circ)$ is as simple as it gets.

Comment: No, it is "find the value of the expression".

Comment: I reduced this to a polynomial equation but it's quartic I think..

Comment: Why don't you post it?

Comment: I'm mobile so it is not easy, but what I did was use the angle sum formula for tangent on both sides of the equation.